# How to prevent replay attacks on ZK Proof Transactions?

Tags: security, zksnark, zero-knowledge

Alice wants to prove a statement (let's say, she has a secret value x such that x * 2 = 10) to Bob without revealing x).

Alice generates a proof using the ZK-Snark protocol.

```
const { proof, publicSignals } = await snarkjs.groth16.fullProve(
          sampleInput,
          "circuits/quadratic.wasm",
          "circuits/quadratic.zkey"
);
// Construct the raw calldata to be sent to the verifier contract
const rawcalldata = await snarkjs.groth16.exportSolidityCallData(
          proof,
          publicSignals
);
let jsonCalldata = JSON.parse("[" + rawcalldata + "]");
```

The verifier contract exposes a public function, let's call it "verifyProof," which takes the calldata (proof) provided by the prover.
**How can one prevent others from calling the verifier contract with the same calldata as the prover?**

```
it("proves the proof", async () => {
        assert.isTrue(
          await verifier.verifyProof(
            jsonCalldata[0],
            jsonCalldata[1],
            jsonCalldata[2],
            jsonCalldata[3]
          )
        );
});
```